# Distinct rows when order by multiple

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am shortening the Query for better understanding.

```
    SELECT c.id, 
       c.code, 
       c.clientname, 
       c.project, 
       c.postedstate, 
       c.postedcity, 
       c.siteadd 
FROM   dbo.employee c 
ORDER  BY c.clientname, 
          c.project, 
          c.postedstate, 
          c.postedcity, 
          c.siteadd
```

I wanted to select all the distinct records which are ordered by the 5 level order by.

I tried by using `Distinct` clause but getting error as ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

### Can you guide me to a solution.

Actual Query :-

```
DECLARE @field1       NVARCHAR(max), 
        @field2       NVARCHAR(max), 
        @field3       NVARCHAR(max), 
        @companyId    NVARCHAR(max), 
        @DojCondition NVARCHAR(max), 
        @category     NVARCHAR(max) 

SET @DojCondition = 'convert(datetime,''31/07/2018'',103)' 
SET @field1 = 
'''PAYMODE'',''CLIENTNAME'',''PROJECT'',''POSTEDSTATE'',''POSTEDCITY'',''SITEADD''' 
SET @field2 = 
'[PAYMODE],[CLIENTNAME],[PROJECT],[POSTEDSTATE],[POSTEDCITY],[SITEADD]' 
SET @field3 = 
',FNAME as [FNAME],CODE as [CODE],PFACCNO as [PFACCNO],ESINO as [ESINO],UANNUMBER as [UANNUMBER],(select ComboValue from dbo.ComboValues where Id = e.BRANCH) as [BRANCH],(select ComboValue from dbo.ComboValues where Id = e.BRANCH) as [BRANCH],(select ComboValue from dbo.ComboValues where Id = e.BRANCH) as [BRANCH],(select ComboValue from dbo.ComboValues where Id = c.PAYMODE) as [PAYMODE],BANKACCNO as [BANKACCNO],(select ComboValue from dbo.ComboValues where Id = e.BRANCH) as [BRANCH],(select ComboValue from dbo.ComboValues where Id = e.COSTCENTRE) as [COSTCENTRE],(select ComboValue from dbo.ComboValues where Id = c.CLIENTNAME) as [CLIENTNAME],(select ComboValue from dbo.ComboValues where Id = c.PROJECT) as [PROJECT],(select ComboValue from dbo.ComboValues where Id = c.POSTEDSTATE) as [POSTEDSTATE],(select ComboValue from dbo.ComboValues where Id = c.POSTEDCITY) as [POSTEDCITY],SITEADD as [SITEADD]'
SET @category = '1' 
SET @companyId = '1' 

IF @field1 <> '' 
   AND @field2 <> '' 
  BEGIN 
      EXEC( 
'select e.Id,e.Code,e.Category as [CategoryId],isnull(e.FName,'''') + '' '' + isnull(e.LName,'''') [Name] '
    + @field3 + 
'  from dbo.EmployeeDetail e   left join   (select * from   (select CustomeFieldName,FieldValue,CompanyId,EmployeeId   from  dbo.CustomeFieldDetail   where CustomeFieldName in ('
    + @field1 +') and CompanyId = '+@companyId+ 
    ' ) as src    pivot (max(FieldValue) for CustomeFieldName in ('+ @field2 + 
')) as src2) c on e.Id = c.EmployeeId   and e.CompanyId = c.CompanyId where e.DateOfJoining <= '
    + @DojCondition +' and e.CompanyId = '+ @companyId + ' and e.Category in ('+ 
    @category +')        order by c.ClientName, c.Project, c.postedstate, c.postedcity, c.siteadd') 
END 
ELSE 

END
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result, all as formatted text, not images. Before you start, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 1):

Try below using row_number()

```
SELECT * FROM 
( SELECT c.id, 
       c.code, 
       c.clientname, 
       c.project, 
       c.postedstate, 
       c.postedcity, 
       c.siteadd , row_number() over (partition by clientname, project, 
          postedstate, 
          postedcity, 
          siteadd
ORDER BY clientname, project, 
          postedstate, 
          postedcity, 
          siteadd) as rn
FROM   dbo.employee )
WHERE rn=1
```

Comment: i tried this but in my actual query there is a left join & also pivot so it is not working.

Comment: i have added in the Question now. please check there.

Comment: ok, you've to put your full query in cte like with cte and then you can apply this above answer on it.